# how to release objects in programs based on UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to release objects in my programming based on UITabBarControllers, all tab bar items launches together at once,

so what should I do for this??

Comment: Why can't you just use dealloc or autorelease pool?

Comment: the dealloc method will not be called when you have UITabBarController, the one thing,,, another autorelease pool, then they are UITextFields, and UILabels, UIImages, can I do autorelease them within body
?

Answer (score 0):

Just release all what you retained. I think dealloc will be called when necessary.

Maybe this will help you a bit:

[Dealloc not called for ViewController](https://discussions.apple.com/message/13024548?messageID=13024548); it's about why dealloc is not called when using UITabBarCtrlr.

Comment: He is concerned how to release the referenced objects without releasing the owner.

Comment: [object release], what else can one do? I don't think you can use local pool for UI. As soon as you add sub-views to some view they get retained by it and all you can do is to release them from your side and later force them out by "remove from superview" or alike.

Answer (score 0):

You can still release anything that you retained, you don't have to do it in dealloc. Just recycle anything anywhere that you want to, and set the object to nil. In dealloc, don't release anything that is nil so you are safe. However, your UITabBarController might still assume the validity of the objects, so it's up to you for implementing the logic.

If possible, you should just allocate a new UITabBarController.